# When are signature petitions made available for potential candidate mayors in Perth Amboy, New Jersey?

Tags: united-states, election, local-government, petition

In Perth Amboy, New Jersey, USA, the mayor is elected. A candidate must first collect a certain number of signatures in order to be listed on the ballot. The signatures, I believe, are required to be on a special form.

I went to the city clerk asking for the required paperwork to run for mayor and was told they do not have it at this time because this is not an election year.  I was told to "come back sometime next year".  I would have though something like that would always be available.

Since I couldn't get a time frame from the clerk, I am asking... when is this material usually made available?  The candidates must be given sufficient time to collect the required signatures.

Comment: Which country and city are you asking about? Not all cities have the same principles. Over here, we don't even have elected mayors so they won't have such forms at all. ;)

Comment: Perth Amboy, New Jersey  U.S.A.  The mayor here is elected.  A candidate must first collect a certain number of signatures in order to be listed on the ballot.  The signatures, I believe, are required to be on a special form.  It is paperwork such as this I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

While this is not timely for your last general election, I thought I would offer the following assessment.

Generally, a petition form does not need to be supplied by the municipality, but does need to have certain elements. Being that there is now a pandemic, many requirements have been modified.

In Eastpointe, Michigan, petition requirements are [outlined here](https://library.municode.com/mi/eastpointe/codes/code_of_ordinances?nodeId=PTICH_CHIVRENOEL_S5PESIFITI) (regardless of a pandemic). While all candidates that I am aware of, have used the form provided by the City, a petition meeting the requirements outlined in the Charter should suffice.

In New Jersey, there are [steps outlined on New Jersey's website](https://www.state.nj.us/state/elections/candidate-information.shtml). The sheet to be used [can be found here](https://www.state.nj.us/state/elections/assets/pdf/candidate/2020-county-petition-1signature-1can-general.pdf). The only local regulations found that apply to the election of Mayor [are found here](https://www.ecode360.com/35009333).